# symfony2 unwanted field displayed in form?

Tags: forms, symfony, field

Using symfony 2.3 I'm trying to use a dumb form based on class form  (without entity) like this:

SearchType.php

```
<?php

namespace Floarc\ParkingBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('search', 'text');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'search';
    }
}
```

And this is what I got in my controller:

```
   /**
     * @Route("/search", name="_farc_search")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(new SearchType());
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }
```

And in my view

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

Simple isn't it...

But when I display this page I get 2 fields displayed instead of only one!

Here is the code of the form:

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="">
    <input type="search" id="search" name="search" required="required">
    <div>
        <label for="search_search" class="required">Search</label>
        <input type="text" id="search_search" name="search[search]" required="required">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="search__token" name="search[_token]" value="oMyq2WORCXyD97WKLb309F0pR1NpDkvVyi8FgqilUzo">
</form>
```

The field I've added has been named with the id="search_search" and a correct associated label, and of course I've got an input for the token.

But I do not understand where the `input id="search"` came from?
Furthermore this input has no label?

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you customize form rendering like in [this docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)? Maybe you redefine standart output

Answer (score 4):

Maybe `getName()` that returns "search" conflicts with built-in `search` form type.

Try changing it to return something else...

Comment: Yes if I use any other striong then "search" it works !
But I return "search"  in the getName fucntion even if I Use aonther name for my class form i've got this strange behaviour...

Comment: This answer is correct. Because getName() returns "search", the Twig block "search_widget" is rendered (i.e. a search input). It doesn't matter what your class is called, but you should make sure that getName() returns a unique type name (e.g. "floarc_search").